# Determining when a radio button selection has changed with YUI3

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, yui

I am using `YUI3` and Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox.  I am trying to determine when a radio button has changed selection.

My HTML:

```
<div id="test">
     <input name="test1" value="a" type="radio">
     <input name="test1" value="b" type="radio">
     <input name="test1" value="c" type="radio">
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
YUI().use('event', 'node', function (Y) {
     Y.one('input[name=test1]').on('change', function (e) {
          alert('changed');
     });
});
```

This doesn't work because the page loads nothing is selected in the radio button group.  When I select the first item nothing happens, no alert pops up.  When I click the second button then it pops up.  How do I determine when a radio button selection has changed?

Also how do I get the value of the selected radio button, I think there are IE issues?  This bombs out:

```
var value = Y.one('input[name=test1]:checked').get('value');
alert(value);
```

And this bring back nothing:

```
var value = Y.all('input[name=test1]:checked').get('value');
alert(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use event delegation to listen to the "click" event. If you don't know what event delegation is, check out [this short intro](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/delegation.html). The change event has issues in older browsers so stick to the click event. All you need to do is get the parent element with `Y.one` and set up a delegation listener:

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
  Y.one('#test').delegate('click', function (e) {
    alert(e.target.get('value'));
  }, 'input[type=radio]');
});
```